What happens when subtract a range without using SUM?
I'm working on a report where I need to subtract 4 values from a pre-existing formula.
FORMULA 1: I subtracted each cell individually:
=('Mar 24'!L812-C4-950)-'2024 Tickets'!K4-'2024 Tickets'!K5-'2024 Tickets'!J4-'2024 Tickets'!J5
FORMULA 2: I selected multiple cells at a time, but I forgot to use the SUM function:
=('Mar 24'!L812-C4-950)-'2024 Tickets'!K4:K5-'2024 Tickets'!J4:J5
Rather than giving me an error because I didn't include the SUM function, I just got a different value, greater than the Formula 1 value.
**Question: When I forgot the sum function, how was google sheets interpreting the ranges I selected? Was it subtracting the first values (K4 and J4) then adding the second values (K5 and J5)? **
Sorry if this is a poorly phrased question -- please let me know if I can add detail for clarity. I'm using 'interpret' in the colloquial sense, but 'parse' might be more applicable.
I tried replicating the problem with a simpler dataset to understand how it was interpreting formula 2:
base value: 100
4 values being subtracted: 1, 2, 5, 6
Formula 1a:
=100-V15-V16-W15-W16
-> I got 86, as normal!
Formula 2a:
=100-V15:V16-W15:W16
-> I got a #VALUE! error, rather than a different number, which stumped me. I wonder why I didn't get an error in Formula 2?

When an array formula that contains a range is not array enabled with a function like ARRAYFORMULA, there are two possible scenarios:

The formula is entered in a cell whose row or column correspond to a row or column spanned by the range in the array formula. In this case, the corresponding value is returned. For example, if you enter =A1:A10 in row 4 of any column, it's equivalent to =A4. Similarly, if you enter =A1:J1 in column D of any row, it's equivalent to =D1



The formula is entered in a cell whose row or column do not correspond to a row or column spanned by the range in the array formula. In this case, the formula will return a #VALUE! error asking the user to array enable the formula. For example, entering =A1:A10 in any row below row 10 or =A1:J1 in any column to the right of column J.


In general, it's not good practice to write an array formula without array enabling it, even if it falls in the first scenario.

Thank you! This answered my question exactly. :)
